# Select a data from MS SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ado.net

I have a table named `t_Student` in Microsoft SQL Server 2005 database. In that table there are three columns named `student_regiNo`, `student_Name`, `student_Email`.

I'm using following code segment to retrieve "student_Name". But instead of showing "student_Name" it shows "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader". Whats the problem?

```
private void GetDatabaseConnection()
{
    string connectionString = @"server=RZS-F839AD139AA\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security = SSPI; database = StudentCourseInformation";
    connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
}

public string GateStudentName(string selectedStudentRegiNo)
{
    GetDatabaseConnection();

    string selectedStudentQuery = @"SELECT student_Name FROM t_Student WHERE (
                                  student_regiNo = 
                                  '" +selectedStudentRegiNo+ @"'  
                                   )";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectedStudentQuery, connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    string selectedStudentName = Convert.ToString(reader);
    return selectedStudentName;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
return (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

as far as you have to return "the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query" (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx))

Also use parametrized query:

```
var command = new connection.CreateCommand()
command.CommandText = "SELECT student_Name FROM t_Student WHERE student_regiNo = @number";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@number, selectedStudentRegiNo);
```

Comment: Thanks abatishchev for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: @towhidulbashar: You're welcome :) Don't forget to accept a right answer. Here and in your other quetions

Answer (score 3):

`ExecuteReader` returns a `SqlDataReader`. You need to use the [`SqlDataReader` API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) to read the data from it. Don't forget that a query can return multiple rows, with multiple columns in each row. For example:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    string name = reader.GetString(0);
    Console.WriteLine("Read name: {0}", name);
}
```

Further note that you should use a parameterized query rather than including the ID directly into the SQL - otherwise you leave yourself open to SQL injection attacks. See the docs for [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for more information.

Finally, you should use `using` statements for the `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` so that you dispose of them appropriately. Otherwise you're going to leak database connections.

Comment: Thanks Jon Skeet. My problem is solved.

May I disturb you again...please? What was the wrong with my code and why it's working now?

Comment: In your code, you aren't performing the Read() method that Jon has put in his answer.

Comment: @towhidulbashar: You also weren't asking the reader for a particular column value - you were effective just calling `reader.ToString()` - and `SqlDataReader` doesn't override `ToString`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (reader.Read())
{
     string selectedStudentName = reader.GetString(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pavel Morshenyuk for your effective answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectedStudentQuery, connection);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

if(reader.Read())
{
    return reader["student_Name"];
}
return "not exist";
```

Comment: Would be better with a short sentence : what is really happening with the initial code for exemple, what is doing this one...

Comment: Thanks  the first code was coverting the whole reader array into a string, you were supposed to get the "student_Name" value from the array through index or otherwise e,g reader["student_Name"] and reader[0] return the same results at index zero